# Java Springboot application returning password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am trying to develop a web app using spring boot and postgres. I used http://start.spring.io/ to create a starter spring project with Postgres SQL jdbc driver as a dependency.
I have added the following in application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password="mypassword@123"   
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

However, this is throwing the following error:

```
2017-07-30 19:09:15.168 ERROR 2959 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:443) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:217) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272) ~[postgresql-9.4.1212.jre7.jar:9.4.1212.jre7]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.16.jar:na]
```

The password is not wrong.
When I use psql to log in to the database using that password, it works.

The pg_hba.conf file is:

```
local   all             all                                     password
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            password
host    all             all             ::1/128                 password
```

I'm using java 1.8 with postgres SQL 9.6 on my macbook pro.

Comment: have you tried spring.datasource.password="mypassword" without @123

Comment: Run this command `ALTER USER "postgres" WITH PASSWORD 'mypassword@123';` and restart your application

Comment: Thank you for your responses.
@user7294900 - Tried that just now. Unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: @AjitSoman - This too did not work. :-(

Comment: Sorry. Meant without double quotes spring.datasource.password=mypassword

Comment: @user7294900 - Thank you very much .. that worked!! I don't know why I did not think of it ...thank you again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your password should be a simple text (without adding characters as `"`)

```
 spring.datasource.password=mypassword
```

Comment: Just adding a comment. In my case, my password contained "\", so I had to make it "\\" to escape the letter, so that my password works.

Comment: in my case, i had a space at the end and never realize until I saw lechat comment thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this when running my application locally and did not manually create my db, user and password. After manually creating them and then rerunning the application worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, in my case, I needed to connect to PostgreSQL, and I had it running in Docker. The first step was to check if port 5432 was in use with the command: `netstat -a`
which it was. The problem was that I also had PostgreSQL installed locally, and it had port 5432 open, so I stopped the process from Windows -> Services. That worked for me.